# Передвижение набора точек с одной позиции в другую за минимальное время

Tags: алгоритм

Задача описана ниже. Пытаюсь придумать алгоритм, но ничего не получается. В этой задаче много проблем. Может есть решение какой-нибудь подобной задачи?

> Дан алфавит, например, русский - А-Я.
> Все буквы состоят из одного и того же
> количества точек. Количество точек неважно, но минимум хотя бы 10-20.  Задаются какие-то две
> разные буквы. Надо из одной буквы
> преобразовать в другую следующим
> образом. Так как буквы состоят из
> одинакового количества точек, то надо, чтобы все точки передвинулись из одних позиций в другие так, чтобы
> образовалась вторая заданная буква.
> Происходит так называемое
> "распараллеливание процесса". За один
> такт времени точки могут передвинутся
> на одну клетку, но не могут
> передвинутся на занятую клетку другой
> точкой. За такт может передвинуться
> любое количество точек. Если за такт
> точка передвинулась с позиции x на
> позицию y, то другая точка за этот же
> такт может переместиться на позицию x.
> Нужно чтобы преобразование произошло
> за минимальное кол-во времени(тактов).

Comment: Ну мне представляется, что надо посмотреть сколько в конечной букве в каждой вертикали точек и при передвижении точек из исходной буквы, группировать их таким образом, чтобы после группировки они составляли набор вертикалей(полос) где в каждой полосе столько же точек сколько и в вертикали конечной буквы, а потом просто сдвигать в сторону пока не упрешься в координаты конечной буквы. Как группировать - т.е. на том же месте где стоит исходная буква или по мере продвижения к конечным координатам, уже зависит от расстояния до конечной буквы.

Comment: Я думаю, если две буквы будут находится в разных местах, например, одна слева, другая справа, то будет проще алгоритм придумать, чем если бы две буквы находились в одном месте.
С группировкой проблемы. Очень много ньюансов в ней, которые надо учитывать. Пока пытаюсь что-то придумать.

Comment: Т.е. буквы находятся одна на другой? Ок, минимальное количество тактов, будет равно количеству передвижений точки находящейся наиболее удаленно от места своего назначения. Можно банальным перебором сделать: сперва делаем оценку - рассматриваем точку конечной буквы и выбираем точку из начальной буквы, которую надо передвинуть минимальное количество раз, затем для второй точки и т.п., искать минимальное количество передвигов необходимо так, чтобы не было коллизий с другими. Узнали сколько будет передвигов, проверяем другой вариант(2 точки могут иметь наикратчайшее расстояние) и т.д..

Comment: Нашли сколько минимум передвигов будет, двигаем. Если честно, эта задачка напоминает нахождение пути в многосвязном графе - когда надо пройтись по всем вершинам по кратчайшему пути, не проходя по одной и той же вершине дважды - задача коммивояжера называется http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0.

Comment: - Вы бы лучше написали, как формулируется исходная задача, а не что-то производное из нее. А то вы ввели много определений (такты, клетки, точки), при этом смысл совершенно затуманился - наверняка реальная задача проще.

- Что такое *клетка*?

- Чем продиктовано условие того, что "в *клетку,* занятую другой *точкой*," нельзя осуществлять переход? Значит ли это, что перед тем, как осуществлять перевод первого символа во второй, нужно целиком сдвинуть куда-то второй символ?

- Не пытаетесь ли вы просто решить задачу перевода одной полилинии в другую? Так ли для вас важна *честная* минимальность

Comment: - Не пытаетесь ли вы просто решить задачу перевода одной полилинии в другую за минимальное число шагов, если учесть, что полилинии состоят из одинакового числа точек, и взята универсальная система отсчета?

- Чем продиктована идея с "параллелизацией процесса"? Это ведь не какой-то из ваших собственных домыслов?

- Для вас важно решение, минимальное с точки зрения количества изменений (а-ля `levenstein distance`) или суммарное "расстояние" изменений тоже стоит учитывать?

- Так ли для вас важна *честная* минимальность или вас устроит и решение, близкое к оптимальному по некоторой метрике?

Comment: Задачу мне эту дали без точной формулировки, поэтому можно кое-что от себя добавить или изменить.
> Т.е. буквы находятся одна на другой?
Да. Я подумал, что вариант, когда две буквы в разных местах, не подходит.

Comment: Можно решить с помощью Венгерского алгоритма. Построить матрицу расстояний между точками первой буквы и второй, найти полное паросочетание с наименьшими расстояниями. Дальше когда известно какая точка в какую должна перейти просто двигаем их на каждом такте в необходимых направлениях. Коллизии разруливать надо отдельно для каждого случая, на количество тактов (на первый взгляд) повлиять не должны.  Если две точки в данный момент времени претендуют на клетку, то на эту клетку может претендовать в конечном итоге только одна из точек, значит другая может пойти в обход (как вариант рассуждения).

Comment: > Вы бы лучше написали, как формулируется исходная задача, а не что-то производное из нее. А то вы ввели много определений (такты, клетки, точки), при этом смысл совершенно затуманился - наверняка реальная задача проще.

Задача трактуется в простом смысле.

> Что такое клетка?

Пиксель на изображении, например. Т.е. если буквы рисовать, то клетка=пиксель или квадрат пикселей. Поле в этой задаче это NxM матрица.

Comment: > Чем продиктовано условие того, что "в клетку, занятую другой точкой," нельзя осуществлять переход? Значит ли это, что перед тем, как осуществлять перевод первого символа во второй, нужно целиком сдвинуть куда-то второй символ?

Если вы имеете ввиду под символом точку, то ответ на второй вопрос Да. Точки не могут налазить друг на друга, но могут идти "паровозиком".

Comment: >Не пытаетесь ли вы просто решить задачу перевода одной полилинии в другую за минимальное число шагов, если учесть, что полилинии состоят из одинакового числа точек, и взята универсальная система отсчета?

Честно говоря, не знаю, что такое полилиния.

В общем случае надо передвинуть точки из одних позиций в другие. В принципе, знание того, что точки будут давать похожесть буквы, нам ничего не дает, поэтому это общий случай.

>Чем продиктована идея с "параллелизацией процесса"? Это ведь не какой-то из ваших собственных домыслов?

Мой домысел. Может тут и нет параллелизма.

Comment: > Для вас важно решение, минимальное с точки зрения количества изменений (а-ля levenstein distance) или суммарное "расстояние" изменений тоже стоит учитывать?

Суммарное не важно. Важно самое большое расстояние.
>Так ли для вас важна честная минимальность или вас устроит и решение, близкое к оптимальному по некоторой метрике?

Оптимальное подойдет, если будут причины на это.

Comment: У задачи точной формулировки нет, сказано лишь, что надо преобразовать из буквы в букву. Буквы состоят из одинакового количества точек и надо преобразовать за мин. время.

Под тактами я имею ввиду ход, как в шашках, например. Только в моей задачи все "фигуры" имеют возможность ходить за 1 ход, но налазить друг на друга не могут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо передвинуть группу точек по глобальной матрице?
 К в А

```
  0123            0123                      
0 .  .             .. 
1 . .             .  .
2 ..        ->    ....
3 . .             .  .
4 .  .            .  .
```

Как на картинке?

Вот примерный алгоритм. Хотя велосипедный.

```
struct ТОЧКА
{
int ряд;
int столбец;
bool дошла;
};

class ДВИЖЕНИЕ
{

bool маршрут_окончен;

// это позиции на которых должны располагаться точки
vector<ТОЧКА> цель;

// текущая позиция точек
vector<ТОЧКА> точки;

void двигаться(int глобальная_матрица_карты[][])
{

bool все_точки_на_месте = true;

// Цикл по точкам
for(i=0; i <= точки.size-1 ;i++)
{

// Если текущая точка дошла, то смотри следующую
if(точки[i].дошла==true){continue;}

// Если одна из точек не дошла, то все_точки_на_месте делаем false
все_точки_на_месте=false;

// проходим по всем целевым точкам
// если целевая точка уже заполнена, то пропускаем её.
// Если позиция текущей точки равна целевой, то указываем
// что точка дошла и целевая точка заполнена.
for(j=0; j <= цель.size-1 ;j++)
{
if(цель[j].дошла==true){continue;}
if(точки[i] == цель[j]){точки[i].дошла=true; цель[j].дошла=true;break;}
}
if(точки[i].дошла==true){continue;}

// Снова идем по целевым точкам.
// Для первой свободной, ищем кратчайший путь из точки i в точку j
// затем перемещаем на 1 шаг текущую точку по полученному первому шагу маршрута.
// после этого выход из цикла.
for(j=0; j <= цель.size-1 ;j++)
{
if(цель[j].дошла==true){continue;}
vector<ТОЧКА> точки_движенения = найти_кратчайший_путь(глобальная_матрица_карты, точки[i] , цель[j]);
переместить_точку(точки[i] , точки_пути[0]);
break;
}

break;
}

// если все точки достигли цели 
// маршрут_окончен =true
if(все_точки_на_месте==true){маршрут_окончен=true;}

}

}

ДВИЖЕНИЕ движение;

main:
// Цикл ходов
{

if(движение.маршрут_окончен==true){break;}
двигаться(глобальная_матрица_карты);

}
```

Comment: Количество точек/частиц должно быть одинаковым.
Я пока не разобрал ваш код, но нужно чтобы буква образовалась в том же месте, где была исходная. Я отвечу позже вечером сегодня(22.10.12).

Comment: @manking, кирилица ух... тут похоже точки будут идти не обязательно до ближайшей цели, а по порядку первая в первую, вторая во вторую. коллизии не учитываются (если только это не делает функция найти_кратчайший_путь).   
@chevchelios, расположение букв - рядом или на одном месте не принципиально, алгоритм от этого не меняется. от расположения букв меняется только количество тактов.